# Axios 'put' request passing array as empty value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, put

This is my 'PUT' request using Axios.

The problem is: the data array inside the variable `userdata` is passing as an empty value to the backend.
but the console.log just before the api call shows the correct value.

```
let userdata = {
  "epoch_time": "1581850307",
  "auth_key": "b22dfe2f8d93445c26f5c261f6a426d2",
  "user_mode": " driver",
  "action": "location",
  "data": [{
    "lat": 20.123657,
    "lon": 80.12453
  }, {
    "lat": 20.123654,
    "lon": 80.12456
  }]
}
```

This is the api call..

```
export const locationTrackingApi = (userdata) => {
  console.log("locationTrackingApi data", userdata);
  return dispatch => {
    axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: BASEURL,
      data: userdata
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("locationTrackingApi response", response);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        dispatch(apiLoadingIndicator(false));
        console.log(error);
      })
  };

}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you parsing the request body on the server?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but I wasn't able. Could you add the code on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 axios("URL", {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    data: loanData
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Successfully Updated !");

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
  axios.put(BASEURL,{
    userdata
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```